# How to get hive query for one to many relation with in a table

Tags: hive

I have a employee hive table with columns name and department. where 1 employee can belongs to multiple departments.

```
name, department
xxx,finance
xxx,hr
xxx,transport
xxx,sale
yyy,finance
yyy,hr
yyy,transport
zzz,finace
zzz,hr
zzz,transport
zzz,sale
```

I need to know distinct employee name who does not belongs to "sale" department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of hive 0.13

```
Select name from employee 
   where employee.name not in 
      (select name from employee where department = 'sale')
    group by name;
```

Hopefully names are unique across employees.

Comment: Let me try this. I think Hive does not support subquery in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a subquery to pull all names that are in sales. Then join that query's results back to your table.

```
select
results.name,
results.department
from
(select e.name
from employee e 
where e.department='sale' group by e.name) invalid_names
right join
(select 
e.name,
e.department
from employee e) results
on invalid_names.name = results.name
where invalid_names.name is null;
```

I'd imagine there is a better way to do this, but this should work :)

Comment: There is only one employee table. there is no Department table.